# How to grab standard date from DateTime object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My date is as followed `2020-05-13T18:00:00+01:00`

I am trying to grab the time, but in standard format. In this case, it'll be `06:00:00 pm`

May I have some guidance on how to achieve this?

I've tried the following.

```
vm.training.startDate = '2020-05-13T18:00:00+01:00`'

var start = new Date(vm.training.startDate)

var locale = start.toLocaleTimeString();   // Produced 1:00:00 PM  (not the value I'm looking for)
var test = start.getTime();  // produced 1589389200000
var test1 = start.toTimeString(); // produced 13:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
var test3 = moment(vm.training.startDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A') // moment date object
```

This one is quite close but still slightly off

```
var test4 =  moment(vm.training.endDate, 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm:ss a')// produced `08:30:00 pm`
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `momentjs` format to convert a date string to the respective format by specifying the format string.

Docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/

```js
console.log(
  moment("2020-05-13T18:00:00+01:00", "YYYY-MM-YYYY HH:mm").format("hh:mm:ss a")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the timezone option when calling `toLocaleTimeString()` method:

```js
var options = { timeZone: 'Europe/London'};
var d = new Date('2020-05-13T18:00:00+01:00');
var n = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-UK', options);

console.log(n)
```